# What to do when Windows can't get the BSOD crash dump?

Tags: windows-10, crash, bsod, dump, minidumps

So I'm running windows 10 on a Toshiba Satellite P50t-B10T laptop and getting the infamous DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION error. The usual procedure seems to be to take the memory dump and analyze it to see which driver is causing the error.

Unfortunately, on my laptop, it gets stuck in the collecting info phase at 0% seemingly forever, as in doesn't move above 0 percent for hours and hours. If I forcefully shut it down, there is no dump to be found.

So far, this issue only occurs with the watchdog error. If I cause another type of BSOD, I get normal dumps.

So my question is: How do troubleshoot the non-generation of crash dump?

**UPDATE**:
Well finally something new happened. The laptop managed to restart itself after BSOD. Turns out, when it restarts itself, it won't detect its own hard drive. I need to shut it down and let it wait for a while before turning it on again. Then, it detects the HDD fine.

The BSOD only happens when playing games for a while. On the other hand, I don't think that overheating is an issue, since the system temperature doesn't go above 85 C and fan doesn't go above 85%

Comment: windows needs a page file to create a dump. Have you disabled the pagefile?

Comment: @magicandre1981 No, page file is not disabled.

Comment: Try changing the dump file settings to a "small memory dump"

Comment: @Moab I'll report back when I have results.

Comment: how large is the pagefile? also have you moved the pagefile from C: to D:?

Comment: @magicandre1981 No D partition on the HDD, pagefile is around 1 GiB.

Comment: @Moab Just had another BSOD, small memory dump didn't help.

Comment: increase the pagefile size or let Windows manage the size.

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's managed by Windows and has size of 1 GiB. I'll try increasing it by hand.